# Hard drive formatting: error message -69760

Tags: macos, hard-drive, error

I can't access my TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 Media external hard drive. Now I'm trying to format it but I get this error message:

> Erasing "TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 Media" (disk3) and creating "Untitled"
>
> Unmounting disk
> Creating the partition map
> Unable to write to the last block of the device.: (-69760)
> The operation failed ...

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Related: [8T external HDD failing to format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360563/8t-external-hdd-failing-to-format)

Answer (score 2):

I've run across this a few times before and there were two approaches that worked:

- Format the drive in a Windows machine (FAT32 or NTFS is fine)
- Zero out the drive.  This, in effect, writes zeros on every single datablock on your hard/solid disk drive.

  ```
  % sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskN bs=8m     ← Where diskN is your disk identifier
  ```

The idea is to write each block with a zero overwriting whatever was there corrupting it.  Keep in mind, this will take a long, long time so if you have a Windows machine handy, it makes sense to first format it there then try again in macOS.

Comment: Toshiba sells only one external SSD (in Germany): Toshiba XS700 960GB, **USB-C 3.1**. All other external drives (64 available in Germany) are HDDs... ;-)