# Mac OS failure cannot fromat SSD drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, windows, ssd

i have a macOS stuck on loading screen tried everything , i installed a bootable usb with yosmite but whenever i try to erase ssd drive i got the following error :

**erase disk failed error : unable to write to the last block**

i tried to format it in windows but got an error : **Cyclic redundancy check**

also checked for bad sectors using AOMEI but nothing found

Comment: It's entirely possible that the SSD has gone bad - which Mac do you have?  Is the SSD removable?

Comment: i installed yosmite on usb to boot from but cannot erase from diskUtility or terminal and yes SSD is removable

Comment: See these two related answers for some possible solutions:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387460/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388362/119271.  However, you may just have to replace the SSD because it's dead/dying.