# Erase Data from Uninitialised External HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

My HDD has most likely been damaged after one day of usage (WD MyPassport 2TB).

Is there any way if I can erase it? I am pretty sure I have something on it.

Disk Utility cannot do it, `69825` error, plus disk cannot be initialised.

```
$ diskutil list
...
   /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *2.0 TB     disk2
```

Running `diskutil erase` does not help either:

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ empty /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed
```

Comment: Try unmounting first `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` then erase again.  However, negative error codes are usually hardware related.

Comment: Similar question/answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388362/119271

Comment: Thanks Allan, it has been lucky read by system and I have my files erased.

Comment: Which solution worked for you?

Comment: After running ‘unmountDisk’, external HDD still could not have been seen by system. I waited for few hours and then HDD was seen by system, although interaction with it was far from perfect. Still, I have managed to erase it.

Answer (score 0):

System has read external hard drive, it seems that after running `unmountDisk` and waiting for few hours, drive was read, but interacting with it was far for perfect.